# Incremental or Online or Single pass or Data Stream Clustering refers to the same thing?

Tags: online-algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incremental or Online or Single pass or Data Stream Clustering refers to the same thing?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22439/incremental-or-online-or-single-pass-or-data-stream-clustering-refers-to-the-sam)

1. Incremental clustering algorithms
2. Online clustering algorithms
3. Data stream clustering algorithms
4. Single pass clustering algorithms

Are the following expressions related ? does some of them include others ? what is the difference between them ? what are the constraints that each one should face unlike others ?